# sendMessage from outside in autobahn running in separate thread by using "asyncio"

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, autobahn

I want to call sendMessage method from outside of MyServerProtocol class and send a message to the server.
The answare is **very** similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799754/sendmessage-from-outside-in-autobahn-running-in-separate-thread) **but i need to use asyncio instead of twisted**.

Cane someone suggest me a solution? An example derived from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799754/sendmessage-from-outside-in-autobahn-running-in-separate-thread) would also be appreciated
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [`call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.call_soon_threadsafe) function of event loop is meant for this.

```
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, \
    WebSocketServerFactory


class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    loop = None

    def onConnect(self, request):
        print("Client connecting: {0}".format(request.peer))

    def onOpen(self):
        print("WebSocket connection open.")

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        if isBinary:
            print("Binary message received: {0} bytes".format(len(payload)))
        else:
            print("Text message received: {0}".format(payload.decode('utf8')))

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))

    @classmethod
    def broadcast_message(cls, data):
        payload = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii = False).encode('utf8')
        for c in set(cls.connections):
            self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(cls.sendMessage, c, payload)


factory = WebSocketServerFactory(u"ws://127.0.0.1:9000")
factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
MyServerProtocol.loop = loop
coro = loop.create_server(factory, '0.0.0.0', 9000)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        server.close()
loop.close()
```

And then from the other thread simply invoke

```
MyServerProtocol.broadcast_message(payload)
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this answer to send Websocket messages from an MQTT subscriber, but I'm running into a consistent problem that `call_soon_threadsafe` seems to be creating ... "partial" instances, with all fields from the parent classes `WebSocketClientProtocol` and `WebSocketProtocol` missing.
Should I open a new question based on this one?